# Finding redundant branches in Git

Tags: git

In git is there a way to find out redundant branches which are already in the commit history of a particular/current branch ?  So that I can delete those redundant branches without loosing any commits and clean my repository as well ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out to be pretty easy, to get list of all branches merged to master just call:

```
git branch --merged master
```

Then you might do following to remove them (use with care):

```
git branch --merged master | grep -v "\* master" | xargs -n 1 git branch -d
```

I found this solution [here](http://stevenharman.net/git-clean-delete-already-merged-branches).